# 2.9 dirty shading on model in object mode when subdividing?

Tags: modeling, 3d-view, vertices

This is my first time creating something like this so it could just be bad modeling, but for some reason when I add a subdivision modifier the shading becomes strange on the model.
I checked the normals and the autosmooth but it didn't fix anything.

[image: face]

Does anyone know how to fix this? And if not, will it show up in renders/other programs?

EDIT: Here's the .blend: https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/eZpLwDyo/

Comment: You could easily check if it shows up in renders if you just render it. But apart from that I have no idea what this is. Which view mode is it? And is there a material on the model? Any other modifiers or just the subsurf?

Comment: @GordonBrinkmann Right, my bad. It does show up in renders. It's in object mode (though it also shows up in edit mode), there's no material, and there are no other modifiers.

Comment: maybe share your file (or a part of it): https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: Subdivision doesn't bode well with non-quad geometry. You do have quads but most of them are non-planar meaning the 4 vertices aren't on the same plane, the rendering engine randomly cuts these into 2 triangles and they are not shaded evenly. The subdivision magnifies this effect, but it is not caused by it

Comment: @Gorgious do you have any idea how to fix that? I tried the "make planar faces" option in multiple ways but it doesn't really seem to fix the issue (unless im doing it wrong)

Comment: You can try to add a smooth modifier before the subdiv and play with the factor and repeat fields, but I think it would take more time to fix it by hand than to recreate it from scratch. I'm far from expert on the subject though so maybe there is an easy fix. I know this must have taken some time to do, but you should view it as a training exercise. You should consciously try to minimize the quad tearing when modelling by hand. To avoid it altogether always move exactly 2 connected vertices of a quad together by the same amount

Comment: @Gorgious Alright, thanks. I'll try recreating it, though if anyone knows an easy way to fix it I'm still interested in hearing it.

Comment: @MeowMilk just checked your file all u have to do is apply scale

Comment: @JacksonPro Oh. Seems that fixed it. Thanks, I didn't think of that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several problems. Here a short summary ;-)

1. apply the `scale` in Object Mode (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>) as recommended by JacksonPro in the comments.
2. disable `Normals` → `Auto Smooth` in object data properties
3. remove/disable the modifiers
4. delete half of the mesh and add a `Mirror Modifier`
5. Fix the oral cavity. There went something wrong. The bottom of the cavity is connected to the upper lip and vice versa. I've added a seam, selected the cavity with <kbd>L</kbd> up to the seam, and separated the mesh to get an overview. It's twisted.
   [image: twisted cavity]
6. Fix the toplogy/edge flow. (Especially the mouth needs a horizontal edge loop to separate the lips. I've added an edge loop (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>) to the corner of the mouth, and used the knife (<kbd>k</kbd>) to connect it to the next pole. Then I've done a lot of dissolve edges (<kbd>X</kbd>) and knife cuts to create a clean topology. It might be not perfect but to give you an idea. You can add a few more edge loops to the eyes (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>) around the eyes if you want to animate the eye lids.
   [image: face topology]
7. Smooth out the mesh in Sculpt move with the Smooth brush at low strength (~0.18)
8. Apply the mirror modifier. Then you can start work on the eye. This should be fairly easily done with the Deformation or Grab brush in Sculpt mode. Have fun!

Comment: im following a tutorial, some parts are intentional. the assymetry is part of the character design. other than that, thanks for the tips

Comment: You're welcome. Yes, I see. The asymmetry is totally fine. But the mirror modifier will save you a lot of time. The time-consuming part is to clean up the topology. That's the hard part. it's a pain and you don't want to do it twice. Restoring the asymmetry on the other hand is done in less than 2min with a clean mesh ;-)